# Envers audit table does not exist when hibernate (via create-drop) tries to delete it

Tags: java, spring, hibernate-envers

i am using java, spring, hibernate and envers among other things. For testing purposes i use a h2 database and for the test configuration i set `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop`. Some of my entities are audited (using envers).

Now, when i run my tests i get something like:

```
2020-04-24 12:05:30.109 DEBUG [org.hibernate.SQL] [Test worker]: alter table nmc.testtable_aud drop constraint FKcmwq41oxs0yus7mgufns1njbd
Hibernate: alter table nmc.testtable_aud drop constraint FKcmwq41oxs0yus7mgufns1njbd
2020-04-24 12:05:30.112 WARN  [org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl] [Test worker]: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table nmc.testtable_aud drop constraint FKcmwq41oxs0yus7mgufns1njbd" via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table nmc.testtable_aud drop constraint FKcmwq41oxs0yus7mgufns1njbd" via JDBC Statement
...
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "testtable_aud" not found; SQL statement:
```

When i use `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` the described error does not occur, but that causes issues further down the line so it is not an option for me.

While the tests run green on my local developer instance it fails on the central testing machine. Also, this is really annoying since i do not want it to throw an error when there is nothing wrong.

It seems to me that this is a really basic issue. I have searched for some time now and tried different things, but i cannot seems to resolve this conflict. From what i read envers/hibernate integration works well so i cannot believe that this is a common thing which then makes me think that i configured something incorrectly. I just expect that hiberate should only drop tables which already exist or at least produce the appropriate sql.

Any help and/or pointer in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that you're seeing this because the schema management system issues a drop of all objects before it creates them?  Do your tests actually fail?

Comment: Well, for the purpose of testing i am not using any schema management like liquibase or flyweight. I do use liquibase for production. It must have something to do with hibernate since the behavior changes when i change from 'create-drop' to 'update'. I just don't understand why hibernate does not generate a more forgiving command (along the lines of 'drop if exists'). But there is probably something i am missing.

Comment: The Hibernate schema tooling system is written such that when issuing drops against the data source its possible those drops may fail, particularly if the data source has no native support for things like _if exists_ clauses.  This should not cause the test to fail however since the exception is logged but not thrown.  If the schema system is then unable to create the table thereafter, the failure to create the table is thrown and will cause the test to fail.